# Kotlin - "If readLine() is null or empty assign default value, else parse readLine()"

Tags: kotlin

I'm a beginner to Kotlin and am loving it so far. I'm curious if Kotlin has a quick and simple solution to checking user input/strings for emptiness. I'd like the funtionality of the following:

```
"If readLine() is null or empty assign default value, else parse readLine()"
```

And so far, what I've come up with is this:

```
var inp = readLine()
val double = if(inp.isNullOrEmpty()) 0.0 else inp.toDouble()
```

Is this the best it can be? I'd prefer to not store the original user input string if possible. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`toDoubleOrNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-double-or-null.html) here:

```
val double: Double = readLine()?.toDoubleOrNull() ?: 0
```

If `readLine()` returns `null`, then the `readLine()?.toDoubleOrNull()` expression will also return `null`, and you'll fall back on the default value.

If `readLine()` returns a non-null value, `toDoubleOrNull` will attempt to parse it, and if it fails (for example, for an empty string), it will return `null`, making you fall back to the default once again.

Comment: Ah this is perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

How about this solution:

```
System.console().readLine()?.ifBlank { null } ?: "default string value"
```

and for password (this doesn't work inside IntelliJ):

```
String(System.console().readPassword()).ifBlank { "password" }
```

Answer (score 2):

## Using the elvis operator and null-safe calls

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val parsed = readLine()?.toDouble() ?: 0.0
}
```

- Using `?.` calls the method only if the value is not null, otherwise it just passes null along.
- Using `?:` means that the value on the left is returned if it is not null, otherwise the value on the right is returned